# Why do I get the subjective message with this title?

Tags: discussion, subjective

The title of my question was "How do you estimate the length of your screenplay in screen time?"  What makes this stupid forum keep telling me "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed"? Does it just say that ANYTIME you start a question with "how"? Because that's the pattern I've noticed.

Comment: For your original question, I'd go back and ask it without the enclosed meta question.  It's a good one, but the body belonged here on meta.

Comment: Question: are you prevented from posting a question with a "questionable" title? Or is this only a warning?

Comment: Only a warning. Just an annoying one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked this up on Meta Stack Overflow:

**[What algorithm does StackOverflow use to determine if a question may be subjective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stackoverflow-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subjecti)**

Apparently the words "you" and "your" set off the filter. I'm guessing this is to avoid the sorts of questions like "how do all of you do [foo]" or "what is your favorite [thing]".

Not an issue in this case, since you're asking a question that's fairly straightforward. My only advice is to keep rephrasing until the system accepts your title.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think that's much of a filter, since "How do you" is an extremely common opening, but apparently it works, so who am I to judge.

Comment: I *think* the reasoning is that "how do you" titles are indicative of polls and calls for discussion, question types that are heavily discouraged on SE sites.